# How can I wrap lines from an input text file to my margins in latex?

Tags: latex

I need to include a text file I get from a C++ program in my latex document. When I include a text file with the latex verbatim include command the text in some lines continue endlessly instead of abiding to my document margins. See picture.

[This is how it looks when it's compiled to pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Kxm.png)

How can I get the input text to wrap according to my margins? I can't change the formatting of the input file because it is given to me with this specific formatting by the program.

Comment: Have a look at the `listings` package, it has an `breaklines` option

Comment: If you were to make a compilable [mre] and provide the text file, I could show you how to do this with `listings`